# How to get rid of the maven-project name in brackets in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, project, rename

I have this project, which I created from the JBoss-Ticketmonster example. Now I was trying to get rid of the old project name. I changed the name of the folder, I changed the archetype-ID in the pom-file, but it still shows me "NewProjectName(TicketMonster)" in the list of deployed projects.

Screenshot: [image]

Can someone please tell me, how I can get rid of it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You know if you haven't renamed the project via refactor it could probably still have the old name in the project config files. Als try to do a maven clean.

Comment: The name of the project is based on the artifactId of your project. If you change your artifactId you have to delete the project from eclipse  and delete the `.project`, `.classpath`, `.settings` files and folders from your project directory reimport the project.

Comment: @khmarbaise, can you please tell me, where I can find those files and folders? I am working under linux and cannot find those.

Comment: In the folder where your pom file is location there you will find them or in the Eclipse workspace folder if you use differnt.

Comment: @khmarbaise, this worked perfectly. Thank you a lot! (I already had found that solution, but couldn't find the folders. They were hidden in the project folder).

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the project new name with `Refactor > Rename...`
2. Delete project (only project, do not delete files)
3. Open project folder and delete .project, .classpath files and .settings folder
4. Import project back into eclipse with: `Import... > Existing Maven Projects` (select root folder with all projects and pick your .pom file)
5. Enjoy new project name without old name in brackets.

You might need to fix some settings you might have deleted (like selected JRE version), but it's easy.